# Programa para de responder quando tento preencher a lista

Tags: c, algoritmo

Esse é o código, ele simplesmente le os valores e coloca na lista, mas no ultimo laço ele para de responder

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct pessoa {
    int horas,minutos;
    int conversao;
    int atendimento;
    int critico;
    int horacritica;
    int horasair;
    struct pessoa *proximo;
}paciente;

paciente *cabeca;
paciente *auxiliar;
paciente *anterior;

void insere(paciente *cabeca){
    paciente *elemento =(paciente*)malloc(sizeof(paciente));


    scanf("%d %d",&elemento->horas,&elemento->minutos);

    scanf("%d",&elemento->critico);

    if(cabeca->proximo == NULL){
        cabeca->proximo = elemento;
    } else {
        auxiliar->proximo = cabeca;
        while(auxiliar->proximo != NULL){
            auxiliar = auxiliar->proximo;
        }
        auxiliar->proximo = elemento;
    }


}

int main(){
    int N,cout;
    cabeca = (paciente*)malloc(sizeof(paciente));
    cabeca->proximo = NULL;

    printf(" QUANTOS NOS QUER : ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(cout=1;cout<=N;cout++){
        insere(cabeca);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Coloque uns `printf` posicionamos estrategicamente para saber o que está acontecendo

Comment: Notei que, ao invocar `insere`, você não está inicializando o valor de `elemento->proximo`, isso pode gerar complicações. Inicialize esse valor, talvez ajude a evitar um laço infinito no `while (auxiliar->proximo != NULL)`

Comment: O problema é que sempre quando chega no ultimo laço o algoritmo para de responder e da erro. Tipo, ele nem chega a ler todos os valores e a IDE trava aqui D:

Comment: Faça as minhas duas sugestões dos comentários anteriores. Se não resolver, você estará mais perto da resposta

Comment: Funcionou. Uma duvida aqui, tem diferença entre fazer isso : auxiliar = auxiliar->proximo e auxiliar->proximo = auxiliar->proximo ?

Comment: tem muita diferença sim. A segunda forma é uma tautologia. Basicamente você está fazendo `var = var` nessa segunda forma, o que é a mesma coisa de não fazer nada. Talvez você ainda caia num acesso ilegal de memória, o que causaria um `segmentation fault`. Por exemplo de `auxiliar->auxiliar` valer `NULL`

Comment: Vou formalizar o comentário só por questões de ter a pergunta respondida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está inicializando o valor de `elemento->proximo` na função `insere`.

Se colocar `elemento->proximo = NULL` logo após o `malloc` já resolve seu problema.

Outra alternativa seria usando `calloc`, que faz uma alocação limpa (todos os bytes começam com 0).

Comment: Obrigado, brow. Consegui aqui